# Appending to LD_LIBRARY_PATH breaks python

Tags: python, linux, path, fedora, maya

I have recently been doing some Maya Plugin-in development,
and in order to link against their API's added this to my `~/.bashrc`:
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/autodesk/maya/lib`
This worked well and now all of the shared libraries are reported as found when running ldd.

However a side effect of this is that I know receive an error when running python from the shell:

```
$> python
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
```

I presume this is due to the python2.7 that is packaged with maya and found at `/usr/autodesk/maya/lib`, there are no issues when running python3. Is there a way for me to fix this without having to conditionally add and remove from my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/autodesk/maya/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/usr/autodesk/maya/lib
```